# Example of a system in $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$ which is complete, but not orthogonal

Tags: measure-theory, orthonormal

An example of system in $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$ which is orthogonal, but not complete could be the system of functions $\{x^{2k+1}, k=0,1,2,3,...\}$.

But I can't think of a system in $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$ that is complete but not orthogonal. Could someone give me an example?

Comment: What about... everything?

Comment: Complete means span of system is dense?

Comment: $\phi_1,\phi_2,...$ is complete in V, if and only if, $a\in V:\langle a,\phi_j\rangle=0$, $\forall j \Rightarrow a=0$

Comment: The collection of indicator functions of finite intervals?